# Apache POI and Numeric Cell Types - Excel alerts of problem

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am finding numberic cells created by Apache POI is showing problems when I open the workbook in excel.

[image: Excel Shows Problems With Cell]

Here is my code

```java
private void matrixToXlsx(@NonNull final List<List<Object>> matrix, 
                          @NonNull final String output) throws IOException {
    //'val' is from lombok and is equal to 'final var'
    val f = new File(StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(output, "temp.xlsx"));
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f);
    try (val wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        val helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        val sheet = wb.createSheet("Query Result");
        val rowNum = new AtomicInteger();
        matrix.forEach(listRow -> {
            val row = sheet.createRow(rowNum.getAndIncrement());
            val colNum = new AtomicInteger();
            log.info("Processing row #{}: {}", rowNum.get() - 1, listRow);
            listRow.forEach(listCell -> {
                log.info("Processing col #{} cell: {} (type: {})", colNum, listCell, listCell.getClass().getSimpleName());
                val cell = row.createCell(colNum.getAndIncrement());
                if (listCell instanceof BigDecimal) {
                    // ################ cell creation for double ####################
                    cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) listCell).doubleValue());
                    // ##############################################################
                } else if (listCell instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) listCell);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(listCell));
                }
            });
        });
        try (val os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))) {
            wb.write(os);
        } finally {
            log.info("Output finished");
        }
    }
}
```

I followed the [help reference](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/CreateCell.java), which seems to show that numeric cells can be made simply with `row.createCell(1).setCellValue(1.2);`.

I'm not sure what I am missing here. I just want Excel to accept the cell type as numeric. I have tried variations of the code such as:

```java
val cell = row.createCell(colNum.getAndIncrement(), CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) listCell).doubleValue());
```

Where I explicitly tell it is of `CellType.NUMERIC` and this makes no difference. I also tried:

```java
cell.setCellValue(((BigDecimal) listCell).doubleValue());
val style = wb.createCellStyle();
val format = wb.createDataFormat();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.0"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Excel is unhappy no matter what it seems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only case where this could happen using that code is when `listCell` never is `instanceof BigDecimal`. Then it is always converted to `String` and thus also set as text cell value.

Since `listCell` is an `Object` and Excel always stores all numeric values as `double`, the check wheter the `Object` is numeric should be like so:

```
...
if (listCell instanceof Number) {
 cell.setCellValue(((Number)listCell).doubleValue());
} ...
```

The class `java.lang.Number` is the super class of most of all numeric objects in Java. So this should fit the most cases.

If that also not get `listCell` as numeric, then the `Object listCell` is not a numeric object. Your code logs the class of each `listCell` object. So look into that log what classes get logged there. If that all are `String`s then the problem is in creating the `List<List<Object>> matrix`.

Comment: Embarrassing how simple that was! Yeah - BigDecimal was too specific. I kept seeing BigDecimal when when looking at types in my debug logs, but when I changed the logic to look for the abstract Number super-class, the issue goes away!

Answer (score -1):

try

sheet.addIgnoredErrors(new CellRangeAddress(firstRowNum,lastRowNum,firstColumnNum,lastColumnNum), IgnoredErrorType.NUMBER_STORED_AS_TEXT);

Comment: This sounds like an Band-Aid? I.e., just a way to tell Excel to ignore the error. Instead of this, I was hoping to find out why I am getting an error; what code do I need to add or remove so that excel thinks the cell is perfectly fine and numeric.